# JavaScript iteration vs filter map

Tags: javascript

I am wondering about the difference between this:

```
function doesCodeExist(arrvalidcodes, code) {

  var hit = arrvalidcodes.filter(function(item){
    return (code === item)
  }).map(function(item){
    return true;
  });
  if (hit[0] === true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and this:

```
function doesCodeExist(arrvalidcodes, code) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arrvalidcodes.lenght; i++) {
    if (arrvalidcodes[i] === code) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Both codes should do the same thing, simply return `true` if the code is in the provided array or otherwise return `false`.

Which is considered the most readable and which is the more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: I would say the second block is more efficient since you exist the for loop as soon as you found something, while the first part is looping through all the items (and it also doesn't read as well. I would definitelly prefer the second part

Comment: which do you think is more readable? and this `if (hit[0] === true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }` can be shortened to this : `return hit[0] === true; `

Comment: @Craicerjack `hit[0]` can never be anything other than `true`, or `undefined` (in the latter case only if `hit.length === 0`).   Either way, using `.filter` and `.map` like this is a _horrendous_ non-intuitive and inefficient way of checking for the existence of an element in an array.

Answer (score 2):

Of course your first code is worse because it allocates various useless arrays and is not readable.

If you want semantic ES5 array methods, use `some`:

```
function doesCodeExist(arrvalidcodes, code) {
  return arrvalidcodes.some(function(item){
    return code === item;
  });
}
```

Of course, for just strict comparison you should use `indexOf`, or is you want a SameValueZero comparisson use `includes`.

Comment: IMHO, in this case using `.indexOf` (or `.includes` if available) is way better than using a custom predicate function with `.some` - there's no point replacing a perfectly good native equality test with a callback.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, that's what I meant in the last paragraph. But for customized comparisons, `some` should be used instead of `filter` and `map`.

Comment: yes, absolutely `some` is better for a custom comparator.  It's worse for a pure equality test, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The **`indexOf()`** method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or `-1` if it is not present.

```
function doesCodeExist(arrvalidcodes, code) {
    return arrvalidcodes.indexOf(code) !== -1;
}
```

or with ES6 use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)